# how to access ip camera (compro IP50W) using OpenCV 2.1 in visual C++ 2010 or 2008

Tags: c++, c, opencv

```
CvCapture* cam = cvCaptureFromFile("http:\\192.168.0.77");
IplImage* img;
img = cvQueryFrame(cam);

IplImage* current = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
IplImage* comResult = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(img),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1); 

double cam_w = cvGetCaptureProperty(cam, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
double cam_h = cvGetCaptureProperty(cam, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
double fps = 10;
```

Comment: Does the documentation for the camera state which URL's the video feeds are streamed from?

Answer (score 1):

Read the [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#capturefromfile):

```
CvCapture* cvCaptureFromFile(const char* filename);
```

> Initializes capturing a video from a file.The function cvCaptureFromFile() allocates and initializes the CvCapture structure for reading the video stream from the specified file. Which codecs and file formats are supported depends on the back end library.

This functions reads from a **file**! You need to have a camera connected to your computer to be able to retrieve frames from the camera.

**However**, if you compiled OpenCV with **ffmpeg** support you can read from a file in the network, but you **must** specify the *filename* in the url.

Notice in the code below that the filename is specified at the end:

```
CvCapture* camera = cvCaptureFromFile("http://username:pass@cam_address/axis-cgi/mjpg/video.cgi?resolution=640x480&req_fps=30&.mjpg");
if (!camera)
{
    printf("cvCaptureFromFile failed\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

Always test the return of OpenCV functions. How can you know if the function succeeded if you don't check it, right?!

Comment: I have same problem, using rtsp did not fixed it!

Comment: I am having the same problem. When I read the manual it says that the address for rtsp is rtsp://192.168.1.128:554/ch1-s1. This kind of streaming works with vlc but doesnt work with opencb as there is no file sepcified at the end of the link. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found this [site](http://vodinhphong.wordpress.com/tag/ffmpeg/) helpful to solve this problem

It purpose  a simple way to solve the problem regarding handling FFMPEG decode in opencv C++ (windows) and now I am able to retrieve image from IP camera using highgui

Comment: Please not provide "Link Only" answers, as changes to the linked site make the answer meaningless