# Read image from URL for openCV input

Tags: opencv

I want to read from IP camera with openCV, IP camera provides a RTSP output rtsp://ip:port/video.3gp but `cvCaptureFromFile("rtsp://ip:port/video.3gp");` shows a blank screen, the alternative solution is using using JPEG output, its url is http://ip/jpg/image.jpg and will every 50ms, but also `cvCaptureFromFile("http://ip/jpg/image.jpg");` returns blank screen; I dont't know do I use it in right way or not.

Comment: Why do you expect opencv to handle URLs? Use some other lib (e.g. curl) to fetch the image, then use opencv to open it.

Comment: honestly, It's first time I'm writing C++ code, I have VB.net programming experience; I don't know how to deal with curl type and IpImage

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413069/how-to-access-ip-camera-compro-ip50w-using-opencv-2-1-in-visual-c-2010-or-200/6414071#6414071

Comment: Compiling OpenCV with FFMPEG solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075180/how-to-compile-opencv-2-3-with-ffmpeg-support-with-visual-studio-2010

Answer (score -2):

I've managed to find a way to load images into OpenCV right away from the image URL. Find out how to do it here: http://techify.giridharsweb.com/2012/08/05/read-image-from-url-into-opencv/