# Still I receive an error "LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_ffmpeg231.lib"

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv

Beginner in Image Processing with OpenCV. I am trying to load an Image in VS2010 with OpenCV 2.3.1. However I have the libraries included and the system variables updated. I have checked couple of other forums suggesting using a different version of OpenCV. I have tried using OpenCV 2.4.0 and 2.3.0 and its the same error I receive. Any workaround for this would break the barrier!!

Comment: I have tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075180/how-to-compile-opencv-2-3-with-ffmpeg-support-with-visual-studio-2010 but no go

Comment: Anyone has the problem above, I would request a workaround for this which would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you check to make sure your directories and environmental variables are entered correctly. Then try manually retyping the libraries in the linker, carefully making sure you entered it correctly. 
**Check in your 'lib' folder (*C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib*) to make sure you put the right file name in your additional libraries.** For example, you could have file opencv_ffmpeg231.lib from version 2.3.1. This may have been the case during the making of the tutorial but change the number to your current version.

i.e, for version 2.4.7 it would be *opencv_ffmpeg247.lib*
just **check your "lib' folder** to make sure they're the **same name**

Also, Try this youtube Tutorial for installing OpenCv on Visual Studio. --> http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgo0UitHfp8